# An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have an application with WF control hosted in WPF window and i'm proceesing some record and playback actions in my project. I get the below exception while performing play back.

**The system cannot find the file specified**

I have searched regarding this and seen some suggestions that we need to provide the full path of the file to process.I have tried this also, but still i'm getting this exception.

Please anyone let me know how to resolve this?

```
var instance = testclass.GetControlForTest();
WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
host.Child = instance;

var testwindow = new TestWindow(testdata, testclass, false, (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow, true);
testwindow.testSurface.Children.Add(host);

testwindow.Show();
await Task.Delay(1000);
Process p = new Process();
var mainPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

do
{
    mainPath = Directory.GetParent(mainPath).FullName;
} while (Directory.GetParent(mainPath).Name != "WindowsForms_Testing");
var targetPath = mainPath + "\\exes\\" + "\\";
mainPath = Directory.GetParent(mainPath).FullName;
mainPath = mainPath + "\\TestStudio\\Syncfusion.TestVisualBase.WPF\\RecordAction\\RecordAction.WPF\\bin\\Debug\\RecordAction.WPF.exe";
p.StartInfo.FileName = mainPath.Replace("\\", "/");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = file; //("..//..//test.xml")
p.Start();
```

Thanks,

Comment: A side note: Why don't you use `Path.Combine` ? No need for all these slashes in front and after the path... makes your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't replace backslashes `p.StartInfo.FileName = mainPath.Replace("\\", "/");`, because windows use `\` for pathes
2. You definre variable `var targetPath` ut do not use it in the future.
3. If you want put path in variable you might use `@` for escaping cpecial-symbols, e.g. `mainPath = mainPath + @"\TestStudio\Syncfusion.TestVisualBase.WPF\RecordAction\RecordAction.WPF\bin\Debug\RecordAction.WPF.exe";`
4. For concatinate pathes you may use `Path.Combine()` method
5. Path for property `p.StartInfo.FileName` must starts from disc name e.g. `C:\`, or dot/s e.g. `.\your_path` or `..\parent_directory\your_path` or starts from file or folder directly, relative current directory `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`

Comment: Hi @Anton,
Thanks for your suggestions.
Now i don't replace backslashes as you said. below is the path which i used,

"E:\TestStudio\WindowsForms_Testing\TestStudio\Syncfusion.TestVisualBase.WPF\RecordAction\RecordAction.WPF\bin\Debug\RecordAction.WPF.exe"

but still i'm getting same error. Is anything wrong?

Comment: If i give it like this ,

p.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\TestStudio\WindowsForms_Testing\WPF\TestStudio\Syncfusion.TestVisualBase.WPF\RecordAction\RecordAction.WPF\bin\Debug\RecordAction.WPF.exe";

Its working fine. Is there anything wrong in my actual implementation?

Comment: Pathes in first and second comments is different. In first case you use folder "E:\TestStudio\WindowsForms_Testing\TestStudio" , but in second time - E:\TestStudio\WindowsForms_Testing\ **WPF** \TestStudio\

Comment: Hi @Anton,
Thanks for your valuable time. i realized my fault and corrected it. Now it working fine.